# Having issue to apply second div based CSS to clicked item in first Div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I am very new to angular.Need some assistance with examples as well.

I have two div's . One is created with ng-repeat and have used ng-click to get the clicked item. I have another div below that which has CSS like

```
style="width:100px;
float:left;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:-100px;">
<img src="../../../path to image" in it.
```

Now I want to apply the below Css div to the ng-clicked item. What is the best way to that? If necessary please provide examples.  My code :

```
<div ng-repeat="p in package "> 
<div class="col-md-3 pack-align-lr cursor-poi ticket-top space-buy-pack active-pack " ng-click="testing(p)" >
    <span class="pack">{{p}}</span><span class="spaces-font">Spaces</span> 
</div>
 <div style="width:100px;float:left;margin-top:-30px;margin-left:-100px;"><img src="../../../path to image" class="eventclass"/>
</div> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="p in package ">
                                            <div class="col-md-3 pack-align-lr cursor-poi ticket-top space-buy-pack active-pack "  ng-click="testing(p)" ><span class="pack">{{p}}</span><span class="spaces-font">Spaces</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="width:100px;float:left;margin-top:-30px;margin-left:-100px;"><img src="../../../path to image" class="eventclass"/></div>
                                          </div>

Comment: @user1851003 add it to your question.edit your question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking questions. Edit your question, provide brief example in [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) or such playgrounds to avoid the question gets closed and to get proper resolution for your issue.

Comment: ok  thank you for your suggestion. I am very new to stack overflow as well. Hence I dont know the things to follow. Thanks again.  Hope some one will answer my question.

Comment: @user1851003, if you are new, it's okay, use fiddle, plunker etc. to showcase your problem so that we can help or support you !!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want modify the style of a sibling element when you click on the first div.
If that's the case, I suggest you "pack" your css rules in a class, let's say `.selected-package`.
The next steps would be to store the selected state in a variable (when you `ng-click`) and use the `ng-class` directive to toggle the `selected-package` css class upon the second div.

To wrap it up, here's a simple demo:

```js
angular
  .module('fancyApp', [])
  .controller('fancyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.packages = [
      {name:'package 1'}, 
      {name:'package 2'},
      {name: 'package 3'}
    ];
  });
```

```css
.selected-package {
  color: red;
}
[ng-click] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fancyApp">
  <div ng-controller="fancyController">
    <h1>My pacakges:</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="p in packages">
        <div ng-click="p.selected = !p.selected">first div: {{p.name}}</div>
        <div ng-class="{'selected-package':p.selected}">second div (is red when you click on the first one)</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want the color to be applied to the selected div only. Once i click on another div , it should apply to this div and previous coloured div should dissapear.

Comment: Hope you got my exact requirement. Thank you very much for previous solution

Comment: @user1851003 I think you can build up your exact requirements based on the provided example. Just use css classes to toggle the display of the elements.